# PyQt6 - define a custom pseudo-state

Tags: css, pyqt, pyqt6

Question edited - I originally asked the question below in regards to widgets not responding to styles on widget properties after the property value changes.

Apparently, these style rules don't adjust dynamically when the property value changes as pointed out in the comments by @musicamante.

So I attempted to use `objectName` instead.

My original question and attempt:

I have defined a `Selectable` class that defines a `selected` property for tracking in the object is selected and also sets a `class` property (for css styling).

I have also defined a `SelectableLabel` class which inherits from both `Selectable` and `QLabel`. When the label is clicked the `selected` property is toggled and it alternates it's text.

For some reason the class is set to `deselected` the styling is ignored. I have verified that the `'class'` property is being set properly but the styling is not being applied.

Do I need to somehow trigger an update to the styling after changing the class?

My code:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt as qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QGridLayout

class Selectable():
    def __init__(self, selected=False):
        self.selected = selected
    
    @property
    def selected(self):
        return self._selected
    @selected.setter
    def selected(self, selected):
        val = 'selected' if selected else 'deselected'
        # self.setProperty('class', val)
        if selected:
            self.setProperty('class', 'selected')
        else:
            self.setProperty('class', 'deselected')
        print(f'setting class property {val} - {self.property("class")}')
        self._selected = selected
    
    def select(self):
        self.selected = True
    
    def deselect(self):
        self.selected = False
    
    def toggleSelected(self):
        self.selected = False if self.selected else True

class SelectableLabel(Selectable, QLabel):
    def __init__(self, selectedText, deselectedText, selected=False, **kwargs):
        self.selectedText = selectedText
        self.deselectedText = deselectedText
        QLabel.__init__(self, '', **kwargs)
        Selectable.__init__(self, selected)
    
    @Selectable.selected.setter
    def selected(self, selected):
        Selectable.selected.fset(self, selected)
        self.setText(self.selectedText if self.selected else self.deselectedText)

class ClickWidget(QWidget):

    pressed = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pressedData = {}
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.pressed.emit(self.pressedData)


marginsZero = (0,)*4
class Tile(QWidget):

    mousePressed = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        layout.setContentsMargins(*marginsZero)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.top = SelectableLabel('Top', '-Top-', alignment=qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, margin=20)
        self.bottom = SelectableLabel('Bottom', '-Bottom-', True, alignment=qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, margin=20)

        self.top.select()
        layout.addWidget(self.top, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.bottom, 1, 0)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
                     .selected {background-color: "blue";}
                     .deselected {background-color: "red";}
                     """)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.top.underMouse():
            self.top.toggleSelected()
        if self.bottom.underMouse():
            self.bottom.toggleSelected()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        appmargins = (20,)*4
        # self.setContentsMargins(*marginsZero)

        applayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        applayout.setAlignment(qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        applayout.setContentsMargins(*marginsZero)

        tile = Tile()

        applayout.addWidget(tile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

So instead of changing a property value and styling based on that property value I attempted to use `objectName`.

```
self.setObjectName('selectedLabel' if selected else 'deselectedLabel')
```

and

```
self.setStyleSheet("""
             SelectableLabel#selectedLabel {background-color: "orange";}
             SelectableLabel#deselectedLabel {background-color: "blue";}
             """)
```

but again this does not update dynamically (the documentation doesn't have the same warning in regards to `objectName` as it does with property value changes).

So... I guess my new questions are: are stylesheets not intended to change styles dynamically at all (Other than styling pseudo-states (ie. hover, pressed))? If I need to manually trigger an update I almost may as well just manually set the properties myself. What is the best way to handle styling dynamically?

I suppose the other option would be to define my own 'selected' pseudo-state and style that. Is that possible?

Comment: It's explained in the [QSS documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types): "**Warning**: If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and set it again.". Add `self.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())` or unpolish/polish the widget. Note that you should avoid using `class` property to identify a QSS class, as it may become problematic for identifying *real* classes. Use a standard Qt property instead.

Comment: Please add a comment to notify that you changed the post, especially after closure, we cannot follow every post. Note that using the object name to change the behavior of the style is not acceptable, not even in concept: that's not the purpose of object names, and you're applying the concept in the opposite way. Even in HTML/CSS changing the id of an element to match a style would be completely wrong in principle. As already said, and as stated in the documentation, QSS **never** consider property changes dynamically. Use a standard Qt property and when you need to update the appearance call »

Comment: » `self.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())` in order to force a style recomputation (polishing). There is **no** other option, that's how QSS work, making them able to automatically change appearance on property changes would be extremely difficult and could cause important performance issues. It *still* makes sense to use properties along with QSS, as it allows further customization in alternate styles or subclasses. You cannot create custom pseudo-states, as they are defined in the private API and don't allow extensibility. Besides, using Qt properties will be more than sufficient.

Comment: Ok thanks @musicamante. In another post someone claimed that `unpolish` and `ensurePolished` were computationally less expensive. Is that accurate? Or does refreshing the style sheet effectively do the same thing?

Comment: It's generally preferable to use `unpolish()` and `polish()` (which is more direct than `ensurePolished()` as it's more consistent), and as a general rule because calling `setStyleSheet()` may require to compute all QSS of each child widget (including special rules, inherited ones, etc). For "terminal" (no containers) and simple widgets like yours, it's fundamentally the same. Note that QSS are as powerful as controversial, as their apparent simplicity may cause issues if used without awareness, and performance must be considered as soon as your application (and widget count) grows.

Comment: This is also one related to the aforementioned reason for which QSS cannot listen to property changes: in fact, they mostly act only on UI events or specific changes that are affected by them. Since a selector could potentially affect *any* widget in the object tree, this would mean that each widget should potentially listen to property changes, including dynamic ones (which may not exist for that specific widget until they're set) and possibly for inherited rules; imagine a program with thousands of widgets (which isn't uncommon) and you'll see how the performance would become a problem.